# POT insomnia plugin installation failed

Tags: api, insomnia, platform-of-trust

I have installed the POT Insomnia plugin following [link](https://insomnia.rest/plugins/@platform-of-trust/insomnia-plugin-platform-of-trust) but it's not complete.
Here is error log:

```
Error: Yarn error warning @platform-of-trust/insomnia-plugin-platform-of-trust > jssha@2.4.2: jsSHA versions < 3.0.0 will no longer receive feature updates

    at file:///Applications/Insomnia.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/bundle.js:99713:16
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
```

What would be suggested to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you specify what OS you are using? And maybe also the insomnia version?

Answer (score 2):

For windows 10-11 users

`npm install insomnia-plugin-os`

Then the plugin you wan to install for example in my case `insomnia-plugin-xdebug`

`npm install insomnia-plugin-xdebug`

Go to C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\node_modules

cut 3 folders
[image]

Open Insomnia->Application->Preferences->Plugins

Press `Reveal Plugins Folder`

Paste copied items

Open Insomnia->Application->Preferences->Plugins

Press `Reload Plugins`

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Manually install with npm:

> npm i @platform-of-trust/insomnia-plugin-platform-of-trust

Make sure it is installed  in plugins folder of Insomnia.

After installation is complete **Reload plugins.**

At least this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try insomnia workspace from this PR  https://github.com/PlatformOfTrust/rest-client-packages/pull/7 since it has updates for that package version

Comment: This has been merged so installation should work now from master